# Is there a way to run "createrepo" command on windows?

Tags: linux, windows, shell, batch-file

At our company we have a release process that runs on windows machines. Meaning we have a batch script that runs and copies, packs files and directories and do some other stuff. 
Anyway, to the point. Recently a new Java project came to life and now we have to configure a release process for them too.
Everything can be done on windows except we need to run the **createrepo** command from linux.
Our options right now as I see it are:

1. Run the command on linux, then copy files to a windows machine
   and proceed with the regular process.
2. Run everything on linux -
   meaning we'll have to rewrite the whole script from scratch which
   can take a lot of time.

So, is there a way to just run the **createrepo** command on windows?

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you could do this using Cygwin.

[`createrepo`](http://createrepo.baseurl.org/) depends upon `rpm`, and is used to build repositories for `yum`.  To work as a repository, you would need to make some type of file server (usually a web-server -- though [ftp may work](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/create-your-own-yum-repository/)).

Further reading:

- [Creating a YUM-Repository on a Windows FTP-Server](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-174508.html)
- [Is there "yum" for cygwin?](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2011-01/msg00259.html)
- [Create Local Repos](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/CreateLocalRepos)

Comment: Do you really need yum in order to run createrepo? Cause we were running createrepo on Ubuntu.
I thought maybe there is a way to just compile createrepo in windows.